# Combine vue-gettext with unit tests (Vuejs)

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, vuejs2, gettext

Combining unit-tests and [vue-gettext](https://github.com/Polyconseil/vue-gettext) I get this error when running the tests:

> ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError:
>   undefined is not a constructor (evaluating
>   'Number.isNaN(parseInt(n))')"
>
> found in
>
> ---> < Translate >
>          < Root >'

I am not sure how to combine these two to work together.

Reduced example looks like this:

`Home.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>
      <translate tag="h1">Homepage</translate>
    </h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Home'
}
</script>
```

`Home.vue.spec.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Home from '@views/Home'

describe('Home.vue', () => {
  it('should render correct contents', () => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(Home)
    const vm = new Constructor().$mount()

    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('div h1').textContent)
      .to.equal('Homepage')
  })
})
```

Comment: What is `<translate` tag ?

Comment: Sorry, this is a translation tag provided by https://github.com/Polyconseil/vue-gettext. I updated my question.